# Nodemail - sendMail Cannot read property 'sendMail' of undefined

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm on a project that is on docker and i wanted to try if the nodeMail is effective.
But i got an error (Cannot read property 'sendMail' of undefined).

I tried to use a ethereal email to test.
You can see i put several console.log and even console.log(this.transporter) results as "undifined"
and got "server | 2020-04-19 14:09:50 error: error"

I have no idea why there is an error here...

If you have any idea... thanks !

```
import logger from 'config/logger'
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'

/**
 * @class Mailer
 * @description Class handling Mailer operations.
 * @method sendHtmlMail
 */


export default class Mailer {

  constructor() {
    this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: 'claudie.schmitt@ethereal.email',
        pass: 'DnWah2bRbw3K5bqyke'  /// i edited the password
      },
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized:false,
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * @method sendHtmlMail
   * @description Send a mail
   * @param {String} to Email to
   * @param {String} subject Email subject
   * @param {String} text Email content
   * @returns {Boolean} True or False
   */
  static async sendHtmlMail({ to, subject, text }) {
    console.log("SENDING EMAIL")
    console.log(to)
    console.log(subject)
    console.log(this.transporter)
    try {
      await this.transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'claudie.schmitt@ethereal.email',
        to: 'claudie.schmitt@ethereal.email',
        subject: "MyCV created",
        html: text,
      }, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("NO SENT MAIL")
          logger.error('err', err)

        }
        else {
          console.log("SENT MAIL")
          logger.info('info', info)
        }
      })
    }
    catch (err) {
      logger.error(err)
      console.dir(err)
    }
    return true
  }

}
```

Solved the solution without the constructor :

```
export default class Mailer {

  /**
   * @method sendHtmlMail
   * @description Send a mail
   * @param {String} to Email to
   * @param {String} subject Email subject
   * @param {String} text Email content
   * @returns {Boolean} True or False
   */
  static async sendHtmlMail({ to, subject, text }) {

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: 'ferminr51@ethereal.email',
        pass: 'QBEYfgdgdfgderGy'
      },
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized:false,
      }
    })

    try {
      await transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'fermin51@ethereal.email',
        to,
        subject,
        html: text,
      }, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
          logger.error('err', err)
        }
        else {
          logger.info('info', info)
        }
      })
    }
    catch (err) {
      logger.error(err)
    }
    return true
  }

}
```

Comment: anyone ? i'm still having this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendHtmlMail` is defined as a static method.

`this.transporter` is registered in the constructor of the class and it is related to an instance whereas static members are independent of any instance.

`this.transporter` will be undefined inside the static method `sendHtmlMail`

If you want to access the members of an instance within a static method then you have to pass them in.

Else create an instance of the Mailer class and drop static from the `sendHtmlMail` method

```
class Mailer {

    constructor() {
      this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
          user: 'claudie.schmitt@ethereal.email',
          pass: 'DnWah2bRbw3K5bqyke'  /// i edited the password
        },
        tls: {
          rejectUnauthorized:false,
        }
      })
    }

    /**
     * @method sendHtmlMail
     * @description Send a mail
     * @param {String} to Email to
     * @param {String} subject Email subject
     * @param {String} text Email content
     * @returns {Boolean} True or False
     */
    async sendHtmlMail({ to, subject, text }) {
      console.log("SENDING EMAIL")
      console.log(to)
      console.log(subject)
      console.log(this.transporter)
      try {
        await this.transporter.sendMail({
          from: 'claudie.schmitt@ethereal.email',
          to: 'claudie.schmitt@ethereal.email',
          subject: "MyCV created",
          html: text,
        }, (err, info) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("NO SENT MAIL")
            logger.error('err', err)

          }
          else {
            console.log("SENT MAIL")
            logger.info('info', info)
          }
        })
      }
      catch (err) {
        logger.error(err)
        console.dir(err)
      }
      return true
    }

  }
  const instance = new Mailer();
  module.exports = instance;
```

Comment: @shreyyas888 thanks! it worked! But before your solution, i solve this issue with another method, can you please compare and tell me if my solution is "ok" too ?
Edited the first post.

Thanks!

Comment: @Jer. your solution also looks good, but my only concern is that every time `sendHtmlMail` method is called it will also create its own transport object.`nodemailer.createTransport` and this might be an overhead. On the other hand, if you create the transport object in the constructor then it is only created once per instance of the Mailer class and `sendHtmlMail` method can reuse it without having to recreate it and thus saving a few milliseconds.